# problems with the output of multiple forks

Tags: operating-system, fork

Hello everyone I have this sample code but I can't understand what is the output of it, can anyone of you explain for me this.

tnx in advance

```
int main(){

 int i, j;
 i = j = 0;
 fork();
 j++;
 printf("i = %d, j = %d \n", i, j);
 if(fork())
 {
    i += 5;
    fork();

    j *= 3;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d \n", i, j);
}
else
{
    i = j;
    printf("i = %d, j = %d \n", i, j);
    i--;
    if(fork() == 0)
        printf("i = %d, j = %d \n", i, j);  
}}
```

Comment: I don't see how you could get that output with that code, `j` cannot be 0 on the first line. Do you mean that's the output you expect to get?

Comment: @Joni It seems that I typed by output that I'm getting wrong(I just edited it now),the problem is that when I'm checking the solution key I'm getting a different one, so can you explain what can be the output of this code

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user3344003 I just someone to explain how does this code work, I'm still new to C  OS

Answer (score 0):

Each time the code calls the fork () function it creates a process that is a duplicate of itself.

fork () returns the process ID of the child process to the parent process and zero to the child process.

```
 if (fork ())
 {
     // Code executes in the parent process but not the child process.

  }
 else
 {
     // Code executes in the child process but not in the parent process.
 }


if (fork () == 0)
 // Code executes in the child process
```

You can then draw out a little tree showing the creation of new processes and what gets output.